# ./Configure is not able to pic xlC_r compiler in AIX 7.1 while compiling Openssl 3.0.7

Tags: openssl, aix, xlc

I am trying to compile OpenSSL 3.0.7 using AIX 7.1 with xlc_r compiler(13.1.3) using below command

CC="/usr/vac/bin/xlc_r -q64" ./Configure --prefix=/pathtodir --enable-fips

When the above command executed , am getting error like "pick os/compiler flags" .

The above command is perfectly working with openssl 1.1.1 in the same machine

Comment: Please quote the complete error-message.

Comment: Try command `CC="/usr/vac/bin/xlc_r -q64" ./Configure --prefix=/pathtodir --enable-fips aix64-cc`